# Using hour in sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

When I'm creating a table in SQLite, I can use, for example, "day DATE". But if I want a hour, can I use "hour TIME"?
In my Java Class, I have:

```
private Time hour
```

and

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("hour", hour.getCurrentTimezone());
```

In datebase, I used "hour DATE". 
I just wanna save it in datebase.
Well, Here is the full code (I think it might help):

```
private DatabaseHelper helper;

private int hour, minute;
private Button hourButton;


private Date hour;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.encontro);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutw = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    hourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hour);
    horarioCombinadoButton.setText(hour + ":" + minute);

    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

public void selectHour(View view) {
    showDialog(view.getId());
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

    case R.id.hour:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, hourListener, hour, minute, true);    
    }

    return null;
}

private OnTimeSetListener hourListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourSelected, int minuteSelected) {
        hour = hourSelected;
        minute = minuteSelected;

        hourButton.setText(hour + ":" + minute);
    }
};

public void salveHour(View view) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("hour", hour.getTime());

    long result = db.insert("selito", null, values);

    if (result != -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.save), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    helper.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The date and time functions use a subset of IS0-8601 date and time formats.

The time() function returns the time as HH:MM:SS

The date() function returns the date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD

The datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

Based on that:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date(hour.getTime());
String databaseValue = sdf.format(date);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("hour", databaseValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have any built-in date/time formats; such values [are stored as strings or numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

You can simply store the hour value as a number, and due to SQLite's [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), you can call the column type whatever you want.
However, this number will just be a number, you have to do any conversions from/to complete timestamps by yourself.